# What changes on Easy Mode?

Tags: undertale-yellow

The options for Undertale Yellow includes an Easy Mode setting. What changes when Easy Mode is enabled?

[image: Easy mode in game config]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Game Jolt's patch notes](https://gamejolt.com/p/version-1-1-out-now-patch-notes-2na6ypkt):

> Easy mode: When enabled, the Hats now provide DEF values for an easier experience (can be changed mid-playthrough)

The [Wiki](https://undertaleyellow.fandom.com/wiki/Game_Config) says it increases your defense by 3:

> Can be turned on or off, gives you 3 extra Defense.